# How do you set environment variables on Cloud Foundry v2?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I need to set up consumer key and secrets for Github, Twitter and Facebook.

On version 1 of Cloud Foundry you could do vmc env-add NAME=VALUE
Now with the cf gem I see I can do cf env but thats it.
I also tried setting a .env file and repushing with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can do a `cf set-env` (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf/blob/master/lib/cf/cli/app/env.rb).  You can also always do a `cf help --all`, which will show you all the commands you can use.

Comment: User-provided variables are they hidden from everyone else?

Answer (score 16):

In addition, you can set environment variables in an application manifest file.

[Here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/cloudstagram/blob/master/manifest.yml) is an example of how to do so (see the `env` section of the manifest with name/value pairs)

```
---
applications:
- name: app1
  env:
    ENV_VAR_1: MYVALUE
    ENV_VAR_2: ZZZ
```

Comment: are you using the Ruby-based cf tool, or the new Go gcf client? the latter does not support yaml files yet.

Comment: should work then... make sure the environment variables are correctly indented in the yaml file as in the example I added above.

Comment: When using manifest.yml should you upload this file to github? I am currently storing sensitive information in it. I want to use jenkins to create a pipline. but it is not receiving the manifest env vars because it has not been uploaded.